# Having trouble writing regular expression for this pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following patterns:

```
4/24
8/14/23
3/5/9/21
```

left of '/' is a number ranges between 1-23
right of '/' is also a number ranges between 1-23.
notice, '/##' can repeat several times.

I tried this regular expression, but it doesn't work:

```
var move = "2/11/23";
var r = new RegExp("^([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])(/([1-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3])+)$", "g");

var result= move.match(r);
```

but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me to modify this to work.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I suppose this is what you want:

```
^(?!\/)((^|\/)(2[0-3]|1[0-9]|[1-9]))+$
```

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/nG9oY0/1

Comment: WOW, that works great! Thank you!

One last question, 
How can I return an array that every cell is a group from the regex?

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really know JavaScript. Somebody else will have to answer that for you.

Answer (score 3):

Since it's not clear from the question whether the solution has to use regular expressions or not...

Personally I wouldn't recommend not using regular expressions for this task. I would find a function like this much easier to work with:

```
function processDate(string) {
    var tokens = string.split('/');
    return {
        tokens: tokens,
        isValid: tokens.every(function(token) {
            var num = parseInt(token, 10);
            return 1 <= num && num <= 23; 
        })
    };
}

var x = "4/24"
var y = "8/14/24"
var z = "3/5/9/21"

console.log(processDate(x).isValid); // true
console.log(processDate(y).isValid); // false
console.log(processDate(z).isValid); // true

console.log(processDate(x).tokens); // ["4", "24"]
console.log(processDate(y).tokens); // ["8", "14", "24"]
console.log(processDate(z).tokens); // ["3", "5", "9", "21"]
```

Comment: The method is great, but beside of validating the format I need the regular exp to split the expression into its groups for further processing.

Comment: Updated to return the actual tokens too. I don't think it's feasible to do both validation and splitting in the same regexp, even with AMDcze's clever pattern.

Comment: Nice :-)

it's possible using regex to split into groups which makes it really clean and durable solution!